# Is there data available on the relative strengths of the World Championship decks?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena

For the World Championships this year, WotC allowed Arena players to play the decks in Best of 1 against other arena players.  Has untapped.gg or any similar "play monitoring" tool put together a "results" comparing these decks as played by Arena players?

I have been unable to find any data, but my google fu is weak.

Comment: I expect that there probably isn't. WotC has taken deliberate actions in the past to try to obscure this kind of data from players in an attempt at preventing the meta from being so quickly solved.

Comment: @nick012000 The point here is that it doesn't matter too much what WotC do as Untapped etc happily go round any restrictions by gathering data directly from the client. (Yes, WotC could break the logging in the client again - but they didn't in this case so the data exists)

Comment: That all said, I'm not sure the Arena data will be that relevant. The World Championships decks were designed to be played in a small field Bo3 tournament by the best players in the world in full "try hard" mode. The win rates obtained in zero stakes Bo1 matches by any player on Arena are probably different enough that I wouldn't trust any ranking of them.

Comment: I remember a YouTube series were Randy Bueler played a bunch of pro tour standard decks against each other to see what deck to win a PT was the best.

Comment: @PhilipKendall not to mention that the average MTGa player doesn't have the same level of skill piloting those decks as the professional players who "built" them, so they aren't playing the deck optimally.

Comment: @Andrew Errr... I did mention that "by the best players in the world" :-)

Comment: @PhilipKendall your comment seemed to focus more on the Bo1 vs Bo3 distinction (the loss of sideboarding drastically changes things after all)

Answer (score -2):

This is not an answer to the specific question asked.  As it appears that data hasn't been made available.

However, a very large tournament, that occured near world championship can be found here:
https://mtgazone.com/standard-metagame-analysis-innistrad-midnight-hunt-week-5/